# Need help explaining and more details and answering the feedback for PCB board

Tags: pcb, board

i need help with my doc. I do have to inspection and assembly PCB board I this is my steps are

1-First, I will make sure the PCB board does not have any damage by visual inspection PCB and see if there is any scratch on the lines that will transfer the power.

2- Check the PCB for possible short or open line, using a multimeter to test the short and open line, open when infinite reading and shorted when there is zero reading while the multi-tester set in continuity or resistance option, I will use a digital multimeter and then start to connect -+15 and test the lines if they go to all nods as our planned. I will check the voltage and the current in the circuit with the multimeter and make sure the circuit got the power all the circuit.

3 Check the value of the components required to be installed, resistors, capacitor capacitance and polarity, transistor's pins which is the emitter, collector, check the polarity of the source voltage.

4- For the components, please verify all the resistor's resistance is correct, since we have a multimeter we will check if the value is correct for all components. Parts Value Results 5- During assembly, check the polarity of the components to be installed, the positive and negative polarity of the source, the polarity of capacitance, the position of the pins for the amplifier.

6. After solder, check if there is shorted line or open line using multi-tester, check the expected voltage drop in the load or other components, be careful using multi-tester for voltage check, it should be in voltage option and not in resistance. Make visual inspection again for PCB and touch some components if there is no unusual heat some components, otherwise, immediately disconnect to the source and check again for possible short circuit. Open circuit Short circuit Resistors Capacitors Amplifiers

The final test, keep the board running for quite some time and then touch some components if they do not draw too much heat, if so, let say an amplifier, does not have a normal temperature, which means there is something wrong with assembly, or there is a short circuit.

---

I got this feedback that i have to follow to make it perfect. Can you please help me with that?

1- Visual inspection: Good idea. How many boards are you going to inspect?  5 boards

2- PCB opens and shorts: You have the right idea here but you need more detail.
You need to list all the tests you are going to make. Below is a picture of the front and back of the pcb. I would edit the pcb layout image and note all the locations that you are going to test and then make a table. Before I assemble anything, I suggest drilling the holes for the standoffs. The screws are 4-40 size. You should be able to find out the size of a clearance hole for a 4-40 screw and put that in your document. Let me know if you need access to a drill.

3- I would make a list of all the components that are polarity dependent. Determining how they will physically go on the board is a good idea.

4- Checking the value of the resistors is a good idea, however to do the check you would need to open the bags and this can lead to the parts being interchanged. The chip resistors all look almost the same. What is your plan for making sure that the parts aren't interchanged. Verification just prior to assembly might be smarter.

5- You can add the soldering documentation as a post assembly inspection criteria to your document

6-Regarding the post assembly electrical testing, you will need to have the circuit powered. Again, take the image of the pcb and indicate and label the locations you want to test and make a table. As we discussed, you should have the expected values of the voltages in your table. With regards to components that are hot, since you don't have an infrared thermometer I don't think this will work.
If you notice components that are hot, you can disconnect the power and investigate but I don't think that this is a reliable part of your inspection criteria.
Also, one easy test you can do is to compare the calculated current consumption of the circuit with the actual values. Also you need to talk about testing the slow rate.

Comment: _"I got this feedback **that i have to follow** to make it perfect. Can you please help me with that?""_- So then follow it. Is there something specific in the instructions that you need help with?

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is basic production testing. In an actual production situation these would be done by the individuals responsible for each step (i.e. board manufacturer check the boards, component mounting check solders and so on).

There *are* industry standard by IPC, on the "acceptability of electronic assemblies"; they are not free however, sorry. If you want to mention them for documentation or see if you can acquire them they are IPC 2221A, IPC 2222A, IPC 7351B, IPC-A-600H and IPC-A-610H. Some of these have some information available on the net, too.

As for your steps:

1. Board inspection: no visible scratch marks, no bubbles on the solder mask and similar. Also no broken edges or cracks in the substrate (done usually by the pcb manufacturer)
2. Bare board electrical testing (that's the official name): correct on the procedure. In production there are special machines which are substantially multimeters with robot arms (these are called flying probes).

Determining the test plan is quite a tedious job, if done well. In fact there is special software that prepares that given the board layout. The basic idea would be that

- Each component pad is connected to each pad is supposed to be connected with, and
- Each component pad is *not* connected to any other pad is not supposed to be connected with

The first part is easy: for example you set one probe on the common ground terminal and then use the other probe to check on *all* the other ground points on the board. Repeat for each signal on the netlist.

The second part is impractical since it would imply doing N * (N-1)/2 (IIRC) tests where N is the number of the pads on the board (that numbers get *big* really fast). So you only check for signal passing on adjacent tracks: in the ground example you identify the nets that are passing near a ground and check for open circuit between the ground and *one pad* of each of these nets (if the nets weren't intact they would fail the previous check!)

3. BOM checking and assembly plan. In the master drawing of the board (the one you submit for fabrication) you have an assembly layer or two (if there are components on both side of the board) where each component is drawn with its own designator (important!). In simple cases it can also do for the silk screen.

As for the polarity designation there are conventions on the drawing but the important thing is marking pin 1 or the cathode or the positive terminal, depending on the component type. Non-polarized components have no special marking. This will be used also in the final assembly check.

4. Component verification prior to assembly. In factories it means put the right component reel in the right slot of the placement machine. They put RFIDs on them to avoid errors and *still* they occasionally mount the wrong part.

Be careful, SMD resistors looks almost the same but ceramic capacitors looks *exactly* the same (only MIL spec have the values printed on). So once they are out of the bag a 0603 100nF and a 0603 47nF are absolutely indistinguishable unless you measure them.

5. Assembly. Reflow oven and wave machine in factories, solder iron and air gun by hand (depending on the part). IPC-A-610E reign on the post inspection. AOI (automated optical inspection) machines actually take images of each single solder joint to see if it's acceptable (and if the components are still there!). You'll simply look with a magnifying glass to see if everything is ok. I recommend cleaning with IPA before inspection, it's way easier to see mistakes.
6. Functional test. That's application dependant of course. Often done with the same flying probe machine or dedicated test fixtures. You apply supply, check that basic voltages and current are fine, like regulated supplies or some biasing, depending on the circuit. If you design the board with test point for this it's easier. Then you apply some stimulus and see if the circuit actually works. In documentation this is called a test plan which is simply a checklist like 1) check for +5V on P1, 2) apply sine wave on input and so on

As for the 'hot component' remark *most* of the time you'll see an abnormal supply current in that case. And you would really need a thermal camera to pinpoint the issue in complex boards.